# Sarcastic alternative to Alea iacta est

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I am trying to sarcastically say essentially you're throwing a dice with only one option.

I was researching and thought this kinda worked—*alea incommutabilis iacitur*—but I don't care for the use of 'unchangeable.'

Given my request is more hyperbole or sarcasm, I am not having much luck with online translations. Is anyone able to give (with respect to context) a translation of throwing a 'one sided' die or similar redundant idea?

alea fatis iacta est

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about something like:

> Fata aleam iecerunt
> The Fates have thrown the dice.

You could even make it passive, which is a more direct allusion to the original:

> Alea a Fatis iacta est.
> The dice are thrown by the Fates. / The game is played by fate.

Adding "the fates" makes it known that *we* aren't playing a game of chance, but our game of chance is actually something played by the Fates, who, of course, have pre-determined our lives.

There are many ways to express this (e.g. "the gods are playing with dice"), depending on how close you want to keep to the original wording.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and time I think I like this one the best I think it would have made the most sense at the time even if it's not exactly what I was looking for (which is understandable considering I'm coming from a modern sense of humor and sarcasm.)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't follow your 'one-sided die' idea, but one possibility is

> alea abiecta est

for 'the die is [has been] cast away' (or discarded). It follows the phrasing of the original tightly but subverts the meaning. I think it would be reasonable to use it to describe a situation where choice has been abandoned (absent context there are, as ever, other ways you could interpret it – but this is equally true of the original).

Comment: Thank you for your time and response. This is great I am still hoping to get something that is more futile (like shooting at the moon to get rid of it levels of futile). I reached out on other forums and got this as an answer -Āleam ūnō ēventū iacis- but I'm not sure this really works. What is your take?

Answer (score 2):

Following the idea of a one-sided die *and* keeping close to the wording of *alea iacta est* will probably be difficult. Contrary to popular opinion, *alea* does not mean "die," but rather "game of dice" or "game of chance." Roman dice games were usually played with several dice, which were either six-sided *tesserae* (very similar to modern six-sided dice) or four-sided *tali*. It is all laid out in Lewis & Short's amazingly encyclopedic [entry for *alea*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dalea).

(This is also why "the dice have been cast" is a perfectly appropriate translation for Caesar's famous locution, and "the die has been cast" should probably be considered a hypercorrection and an inferior translation.)

But anyway, I think one option would be to say:

> Alea praedestinata iacta est.

... a pre-determined game. (Although that's not particularly sarcastic, I guess.)

Or you could go with the one-sided idea and use a word for die:

> Tessera unum latus habens iacta est.

All in all, in a sarcastic tone you could for example say something like:

> Alea sane iacta est -- tesseram quidem iecisti unum latus habentem!

(A one-sided die is not a geometrical impossibility, by the way; you can buy them, they are shaped like a Möbius strip. Throwing one as a game of chance *is* pointless, though.)